# DictReader is not behaving as expected

Tags: python

My reader doesn't read and print the rows of the CSV file created in the code above it.

The CSV file is generated and is structured as follows (pasted from the CSV file)...

```
id,Timing,GETQUOTE,PORTFOLIO,GETHOLDINGS,LOGOUT,QUOTES,GETCLOSEDORDERS,BUY,HOME,SELL

0,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.

1,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.

2,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.
```

Output:

```
From 'print fields':

['id', 'Timing', 'GETQUOTE', 'PORTFOLIO', 'GETHOLDINGS', 'LOGOUT', 
 'QUOTES', 'GETCLOSEDORDERS', 'BUY', 'HOME', 'SELL']

print r: {' ': None, "'": None, ',': None, 'C': None, 'B': None, 'E': 
          None, 'D': None, 'G': None, 'F': None, 'I': None, 'H': None, 
          'M': None, 'L': None, 'O': None, 'N': None, 'Q': None, 'P': 
          None, 'S': None, 'R': None, 'U': None, 'T': None, 'Y': None, 
          '[': 'id', ']': None, 'd': 'PORTFOLIO', 'g': None, 'i': 
          None, 'm': 'SELL', 'n': None}

from 'print(r['id'])'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WJones\Documents\wrkin\flattenXML\eclipse\flattenXML\source\XMLflat2.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(r['id'])
KeyError: 'id'



with open('temp_metrix.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    #writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    for r in reader:
        print 'print r:', r
        **print(r['id'])**
```

What am I missing here?

edit:
Thanks for the feedback. I've cleaned up the code to only show what's needed.
csv file link:  https://app.box.com/s/z69t1n97lzhjsu51sf0ipr8my68c4b74

Comment: I tried to salvage the formatting of the csv and print output. However, I have no idea how your code should be indented. Please fix your code formatting to have the proper indentation. Also, please be aware that your code is not a minimal, reproducible example – we cannot run it to debug it. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for preparing the information required for us to help you.

Comment: Can you strip the code to only what's essential for the question? It's great that you are showing an example file, looks like it eliminates the need to show us the code you used to generate it. The problem is probably with `fieldnames=fields` messing up the keys in the dict. Maybe you should keep the original header or debug whatever happens with `fields`.

Comment: What do you think `fields = str(metricsWriter_head)` does?

Comment: I've cleaned up the post so it should be cleaner and reproducible. Also included the value of fields in the output. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: so @LevLevitsky, you've helped fix the problem. As my csv file does have the fieldnames in it, defining fieldnames is both unnecessary and removing the definition fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the csv file has the fieldnames in it, defining fieldnames was unncessary and caused the problem. Thanks for the feedback!

This works now.

```
with open('temp_metrix.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for r in reader:
        print 'print r:', r
        print(r['id'])
```